# Select dynamic columns in a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in the table that contains the surcharge price of many carriers in many years. Each carrier will have 12 months.

```
CARRIER_ID  YEAR    MONTH   RATE
DHL         2021    April   16.5
DHL         2021    August  18.5
DHL         2021    December    0
DHL         2021    February    14
DHL         2021    January 12.5
DHL         2021    July    17.75
DHL         2021    June    17
DHL         2021    March   15
DHL         2021    May 17
DHL         2021    November    0
DHL         2021    October 0
DHL         2021    September   0
FedEx       2021    April   16.5
FedEx       2021    August  17.5
FedEx       2021    December    0
FedEx       2021    February    14.5
FedEx       2021    January 13.5
FedEx       2021    July    17.5
FedEx       2021    June    17
FedEx       2021    March   16
FedEx       2021    May 16.5
FedEx       2021    November    0
FedEx       2021    October 0
FedEx       2021    September   0
```

And I want to make a query in SQL server to get data like this.

Please note that: The data need to group by the year(exp: 2021)

```
Month   DHL FedEx
January 12.50%  13.50%
February14.00%  14.50%
March   15.00%  16.00%
April   16.50%  16.50%
May     17.00%  16.50%
June    17.00%  17.00%
July    17.75%  17.50%
August  18.50%  17.50%
September0  0
October 0   0
November0   0
December0   0
```

I did search in google but can not find the solution.
Pls give me how to do it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: No images please. The sample data is (almost) properly formatted, do the same with the expected result!

Comment: Yes, i am edited the result data. Thank you so much.

Comment: this is a PIVOT.  there are a few alternative methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you do know your list of carriers, you can do it like this with standard sql

```
select
  t.YEAR,
  t.MONTH,
  max(case when t.CARRIER_ID = 'DHL' then t.RATE else NULL) as DHL,
  max(case when t.CARRIER_ID = 'FedEx' then t.RATE else NULL) as FedEx
from your_table t
group by t.YEAR, t.MONTH
order by t.YEAR, t.MONTH
```

`YEAR` and `MONTH` are usually reserved words, so it's not recommended to use them in your data.

Comment: It still cannot solve the problem. Thank you bros.